# How do you install pyvisa?

Tags: python, installation

I am trying to install and use the latest version of pyvisa.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVISA

However I do not comprehend the installation instructions.
For example, I am not using "pip" or "easy install" whatever they are, and 
"$ python setup.py install" means nothing to me.

Can anyone help me out and give me instructions on how to install pyvisa?

Thanks

Comment: did you try looking at the pip docs? https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html

Comment: Yes. It would be nice if they actually explained what "$ pip install SomePackage" is supposed to mean. What do I do with that?

Comment: the $ is from a  shell prompt the rest is the command. It is pretty simple, install pip with get-pip.py. Then pip install package_name

Comment: Ok. Still does nothing.... 
I replace "python setup.py install", with "python filepath\setup.py install".
"install not defined" is the response.

Comment: Ok, thanks Padraic, that helped eventually. Pyvisa working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer in Padraic cunninghams comment. Read the documentation. Had to re install python first though, due to conflicting multiple python installations.